# Audio component is not working in mobile using sencha touch

Tags: extjs, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

The audio component is working fine in Chrome. After I build the source to minified version and took build in mobile. I can't able to play the audio file. It shows

```
10-08 17:05:27.221: E/MediaPlayer(32506): Error (1,-2147483648)
10-08 17:05:30.965: E/MediaPlayer(32506): Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
```

View.js

```
  {
    xtype: 'audioplayer', 
    url  : 'resources/audio/crash.mp3'
   },
```

I included the **'Ext.audio'** and **'Ext.ux.AudioPlayer'** in app.js and included the audioplayer.js.

This is working fine in chrome, but not in mobile.